# How can i perform caching on drupal menu

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any way to do the caching only for drupal menu. I don't want to cache other pages. Just menu only. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The menu is always cached as far as I know, regardless of performance settings. so, the answer is 'yes', just disable the page cache settings... :)